# I would like to do a While loop using HTML and JavaScript however with my current code the loop is not ending

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, while-loop

Currently the loop is running constantly. It seems my else function is not being read properly. Could someone please send some assistance.

Also when I run it on Google Chrome, the first thing to pop up is a "Hello Null" box meaning that the window.alert function is running automatically.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>JavaScript Example</title>
    <script>
      "use strict";
        function start() {
          let ino = window.prompt("What is your name?");
          window.alert("Hello " + ino);
          while (ino != "end") {
            let ino = window.prompt("What is your name?");
            window.alert("Hello " + ino);}
        else {window.alert("go away now mate"); }
            }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body onLoad="start()"> 
    <p>Javascript Test Page</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: At this moment you are using  1 variable ino and it is never set to be "end" so it will always continue.
let ino = "end" set to somewhere would end the loop. 

Where do you actually put "ino" to the string value of "end" that part missing in your code.

Comment: Second your code is not validating, when put in an browser your code said: "unexpected token 'else'. 

the "while else" is not a valid construction 
just remove the else and put it below the brackets. of the while loop.

Comment: When the user types "end" I want the loop to end. Until then I want it to continue asking for the user's name and outputting it

Comment: You are confusing a **`while {...}` construct** with an **`if {...} else {...}` construct**. *Javascript does not have a `while-else` construct*. In fact, I know of not a single programming language that does have that...

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are trying to prompt until the user identifies themselves as "end".
If that's the case, you probably want a do...while around the prompt.

```
let name;
do {
    name = window.prompt....;
} while (name !== 'end');
```

Note that you are mixing 2 goals without a well defined usecase. If you want to tell them to `go away mate` should you be using a while loop? A while loop sounds like you want to keep asking the question. The if...else makes it seem like you want to validate their entry and `reject` if it's not "end". If your actual goal is to ask the user twice then keep a count and use the count as a condition in your while loop. `while (name !== 'end' && count < 3)`. You can can tell the user to "buzz off" after your while loop is complete AND there's name is still not `end`

Your other question, it makes sense that it shows your prompt as soon as the page loads because you are binding it to onLoad event. Shouldn't it?

Comment: My goal is that once the user inputs end, the program will not ask for anymore names. so me putting != is me ensuring it is not equal to end

Comment: Yes it is. So, you are saying `If the name ISNOTEQUAL end... prompt again`. If the user actual inputs 'end', the while will evaluate to false and it'll break out of the loop (it'll end).

Answer (score 0):

Watching at louis answer; I have similar questions and added the code below as an example implementation. please try it and use the console browser to check if there aren't any errors next time. Before adding the code online.

- also pay attention to indents, and be consistent with them below is an example.
- use variables which are readable, another developer might not know what ino means.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>JavaScript Example</title>
    <script>
      "use strict";
        function start() {
            let name = window.prompt("What is your name?");
            let count = 1;

            while (name !== "end" && count <= 3) {
                window.alert("Hello " + name);
                name = window.prompt("What is your name?");
                count++;
            }
            window.alert("go away now mate"); 
        }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body> 
  <button onclick="start()">start</button>
    <p>Javascript Test Page</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That is some excellent coding my friend. Thank you very much. 3 questions; is my check '!=' not valid or do I need to do '!=='. And you say that with a While loop you do not need else. Lastly would the loop still end with 'end' inputted without the count.

Comment: 1 To answer your questions it goes about type comparison or knowing for sure you deal with a String, please look at the link a or a more detailed answer.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness
2.  While does not need a else in javascript and is invalid javascript see F12 on chrome for developer tools (look at console) to see if any code contains errors.
3. a while loop keeps going while the condition is true. when the condition is broken it continues to the next piece. inside while block repeats, until either "end" is found or count is > 3

Comment: You could add a if(name !== "end"){  all code... } inside the while block and it won't alert when "end" is found for example.